# referring to files in style library from content editor web part

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, content-editor-web-part

I have a content editor webpart

I am referring a html file to the content link of the webpart

the contentLink looks something like the one below

```
sites/ImageList/Style Library/Page/ImageList.html
```

It works fine in my machine but when i deploy the wsp in other machine, its not loading the page as the "`sites/ImageList`" will be changing

How can i have this working in any machine? 
The files are there in style library and it works after i manually change it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Pradip has already told the reason for this behaviour I won't repeat it here again. But there are a couple of things you can try.

Have a look at this article, [Inconvenient Content Query Web Part and server-relative URLs](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/inconvenient-content-query-web-part-server-relative-urls/), which suggests -

> Another way to get around this issue is to use a Feature Receiver.
>   After activating the Feature that provisions the .webpart file of the
>   Content Query Web Part with custom XSLT files, it would modify the
>   contents of the .webpart file and replace the tokens with
>   server-relative URL of the current Site Collection.

The aforementioned article also provides code snippet which you can give a try.

You can also look into using URL tokens by changing the code within the `Elements.xml` file of Content Editor Web Part as below:

```
<ContentLink xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor">~site/Style Library/Page/ImageList.html</ContentLink>
```

Please look into the discussions over [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0e74ce73-7fce-4c09-a1ab-aafe62d53668/url-tokens-in-content-editor-webpart) and [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/5361ed95-30f1-476f-968c-676da018c695/url-token-sitecollection-within-elementsxml-file-contentlinksitenamelists) for more information on using URL tokens in CEWP.

Comment: stuck with the same issue and this answer is not working now!

Answer (score 4):

If you enter a URL into the Content Editor Web Part as a relative link, the link converts to an absolute URL when the entry is saved. This automatic conversion can be an issue if you are deploying content from a staging environment to production, where absolute URLs reference the original server's name.

To address this automatic conversion issue,

**You will need to edit the Content Editor Web Part on the production server and update the URLs manually.**

Read more [here](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Content-Editor-Web-Part-c1350ff6-934c-4c2e-8e53-1ec3b548a0dc).

Answer (score 1):

As per [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/PointsToShare/archive/2012/05/01/relative-and-absolute-urls-in-cewp.aspx) article, I've:

> Put the CEWP HTML in a text file, relative URL included and put it in
>   a document library. Put the link to this text file in the CEWP.

[image: CEWP Content Link]