# (SharePoint 2010) Fix URL in Content Editor

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, url

I made a button that points to a specific URL on my SharePoint site. When I add my button using "Edit HTML Source" and save SharePoint changes the absolute URL to a relative URL which causes my button to not work.

Should I be doing something differently? When I open my button in a browser it works fine using the full URL, it is only when I add it to SP2010 that the shortened URL doesnt work.

In addition to directly editing the source html for the web part I have also tried linking to an html and text file, both of which get the url shortened by SharePoint.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a security feature implemented by Microsoft to avoid cross site scripting. Because of this feature, SharePoint changes the absolute URL to a relative URL.

The only OOTB way to surpass this is by putting your content in a `.txt` file, Upload it to some location within your SharePoint and using Content Link.

If you still not able to get it then kindly check the answer at below article.

[referring to files in style library from content editor web part](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/142972/referring-to-files-in-style-library-from-content-editor-web-part)

Comment: Thanks, but when I try that it changes the URL I am using to a link for the page the button is on. Specifically, the button is on the home page and when I use the text file the button takes the user back to the home page instead of to the url specified in the txt file. Any thoughts on why?

Comment: I am not getting you point. I understood that you need button on home page using CEWP. The button have the link applied on it. & that link on the button changes from absolute to relative. Am i correct? Please correct me if i am worng

Comment: Yes, it changes from absolute to relative and the relative link does not work - the button returns the user to the page the button is on instead of taking them to the page the link is for.

Comment: If you can share me your code than I will try to help you.