# Change the contentlink based on Site collection

Tags: 2013, 2010, content-editor-web-part

I have a html file in the style library which I am loading onto a **content editor webpart** using content link

Currently i have used,

```
/sites/sitename/style library/html/file.htm
```

But here the **sitename** is hard coded, and it will not work when exported to other site collections.

I also thought about using

```
../style library/html/file.htm
```

But this might not work  for pages in subsites or pages hosted in sub folders in a document library

Is there a more generic way to point to style library of site collection?

something like `~sitecollection`

Answer (score 2):

**JSLink URLs and Tokens**

When you are constructing your JSLink URL there are a number of tokens you can take advantage of:

1. ~site – reference to the current SharePoint site (or “Web”)
2. ~sitecollection – reference to the current SharePoint site
   collection (or “Site”)
3. ~layouts – version specific reference to the web application Layouts
   folder (so it will automatically swap out /_layouts/14 or
   /_layouts/15 for you)
4. ~sitecollectionlayouts – reference to the layouts folder in the
   current site collection (e.g. /sites/team/_layouts/15)
5. ~sitelayouts – reference to the layouts folder in the current site
   (e.g. /sites/teams/subsite/_layouts/15)

[Overview, URL Tokens and Applying JSLink to objects](https://www.martinhatch.com/2013/08/jslink-and-display-templates-part-1.html)

Comment: Thanks Tarun
JSLink option is not available in Content editor webpart
I am giving content links and exporting the webpart

Comment: please check this https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/142972/referring-to-files-in-style-library-from-content-editor-web-part